# finding the combination (nCr) when n is greater than 150!

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

I am given a question saying "Let X be a binomial random variable with n = 150 and p = .382; find P(X = 32) and P(X <= 30)."
In order to solve this, I feel like I have to use the binomial distribution: (nCx)(p^x)[(1-P)^(n-x)] but since n = 150, my calculator spits out "OVERFLOW". 
is there a way to solve this in such a way without using online calculators and excel formula functions? I'd like to get prepared if this kind of question comes up in an exam where I can only depend on my scientific calculators.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to not have an exclamation mark in the title - I see that and think you mean $n\geq 150!=150\cdot 149 \cdot \ldots$, which is a lot bigger.

Comment: $a = \exp\left(\ln\left(a\right)\right)$. Calculate the "$\ln$" first if you are using a calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $n$ is large, it is enough to use the normal distribution to approximate the binomial. Many standard scientific calculators choke on 69! or so.

To do this, the mean will be $np$, the number of trials times the probability of success, and the variance is $npq$, just the mean times the probability of failure.